# What kind of unit test do I use for a Silverlight class library (non UI)

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing

I have a solution built up of several projects. One is a Silverlight 4 application library used for the ViewModel. This contains no UI code so I have no need for UI specific testing. I Only want to test the logic in the ViewModel.

Can I use a normal Unit test project in Visual Studio or do I need to go down the Silverlight Unit Testing route?

If I can't use a normal test project, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to checkout SilverUnit - it may take care of what you're after - http://cthru.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SilverUnit%20examples&referringTitle=Home&ProjectName=cthru

http://blog.typemock.com/2009/02/silverunit-true-unit-testing-for.html

http://site.typemock.com/silverlight_unit_testing_page

As of last check, though, you do need a TypeMock license to use it, though.

Comment: Seems as if SL unit testing is still a pain, hoping for something better to come along.